# How to make ajax call in bootstrap typehead

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

Here is my jquery code to set up bootstrap typehead from local source

```
    $(function () {

    var src = [{ id: 1, name: 'Toronto', state: 'ON', country: 'Canada', key: 12345 },
                    { id: 2, name: 'Montreal', state: 'QC', country: 'Canada', key: 23456 },
                    { id: 3, name: 'New York', state: 'NY', country: 'USA', key: 34567 },
                    { id: 4, name: 'Buffalo', state: 'NY', country: 'USA', key: 45678 },
                    { id: 5, name: 'Boston', state: 'MA', country: 'USA', key: 56789 },
                    { id: 6, name: 'Columbus', state: 'OH', country: 'USA', key: 67890 },
                    { id: 7, name: 'Dallas', state: 'TX', country: 'USA', key: 78901 },
                    { id: 8, name: 'Vancouver', state: 'BC', country: 'Canada', key: 89102 },
                    { id: 9, name: 'Seattle', state: 'WA', country: 'USA', key: 90123 },
                    { id: 10, name: 'Los Angeles', state: 'CA', country: 'USA', key: 11234}];

    localStorage.setItem("cities", JSON.stringify(src));

    $('#search').typeahead({
        sources: [
        { name: "local", type: "localStorage", key: "cities" }
      ]
    });

});
```

Its working fine.
How to do an ajax call from a server and hook up a similar data as shown above with the source.

***`update`:***
here is a above working code on jsfiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/MMarW/`

And here is the ajax code on jsfiddle that is not firing `http://jsfiddle.net/FZP8a/3/`

Answer (score 0):

Provide function as source:

```
$('#search').typeahead({
  source: function(query, process) {
    var searchUrl = YOUR_URL + '?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query);

    $.get(searchUrl)
    .success(function(data){
      //... do whatever you want...
      // ... and pass array to process function
      process(dataArray);
    })
    .error(function(){
      //...handle error
    });
  }
});
```

You may also return dataArray directly from source function. More info in [docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) under options.

edit: to request jsonp, use jQuery.ajax:

```
$('#search').typeahead({
  source: function(query, process) {
    var searchUrl = YOUR_URL + '?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query);

    $.ajax(searchUrl, {
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       crossDomain: true // probably needed
    }).success(function(data){
      //... do whatever you want...
      // ... and pass array to process function
      process(dataArray);
    }).error(function(){
      //...handle error
    });
  }
});
```

Get more info on jsonp in [jQuery.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

and actually $.get is just a shorthand for $.ajax.

Comment: i get data as jsonp so i have to use jsonpcallback function so in dat case how can i use a .success

Comment: is it possible to use a callback function instead of success

Comment: i just tried with the way u told but the ajax is not at all firing

Comment: debug it in console/firebug/etc

Comment: i tried but the call comes to the source portion but then does come back either to the success part or to the error part.do u mind having a look if i host it some where?

Comment: i just updated the question with link to jsfiddle.have a look